# how to update all rows of a specified data group in SQL server based on a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data:

[image]

I need to update the "IsConsideredNewHire" column so that if there is a ZERO in the control group related to it, all other rows for that control group should be ZERO.

after the update, you'd get something like this:

[image]

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get this accomplished.

Anyone want to give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET IsConsideredNewHire = 0
WHERE ControlGroupID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ControlGroupID 
                         FROM MyTable
                         WHERE IsConsideredNewHire=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using window fuunctions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select d.*, min(IsConsideredNewHire) over (partition by ControlGroupId) as minIsConsideredNewHire
      from data
     )
update toupdate
    set IsConsideredNewHire = 0
    where minIsConsideredNewHire = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with x as 
(select row_number() over(partition by controlgroupid order by isconsiderednewhre) as rn, * from tablename)
update tablename set isconsiderednewhre = 0 where controlgroupid = 
(select controlgroupid from x where rn = 1 and isconsiderednewhre = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `EXISTS()` with the simple `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE u
SET IsConsideredNewHire = 0
FROM [data] u
WHERE 
    u.IsConsideredNewHire = 1 -- Consider update for new hire only
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM [data] -- This * is just fine, optimizer knows no data to be return
        WHERE ControlGroupId = u.ControlGroupId AND IsConsideredNewHire = 0
    )
```